# Statistics of application updates Itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Where can I find how many percents uses the latest update of my application? I found only updates by days but not in general. I use iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iTunesConnect -> App Analytics -> Your App -> Metrics -> Active Devices
Then click Add Filter button and select App Version - select version you need
You'll see metrics for selected app version only. Not percentage though, but anyway you can compare adoption for different versions.
If you want percentages - you could try fabric.io analytics.